# Web service en python

Tags: python

Hola que tal la verdad soy nueva en esto y quiero conectarme al web service del banco de México para obtener el tipo de cambio, lo cual lo estoy haciendo en Python.

Hasta ahora ya logré conectarme al web service de banxico con el siguiente código:

```
from suds.client import Client

client = Client('http://www.banxico.org.mx:80/DgieWSWeb/DgieWS?WSDL')
#print client

response = client.service.tiposDeCambioBanxico()
print response
```

pero me arroja todos los tipos de cambio y yo solo necesito el del dólar.

Espero alguien pueda orientarme a solo sacar ese valor.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes procesar el xml obtenido mediante [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) se la biblioteca estándar y buscar la información que deseas usando xpath:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from suds.client import Client

client = Client('http://www.banxico.org.mx:80/DgieWSWeb/DgieWS?WSDL')
xml_tree = ET.fromstring(client.service.tiposDeCambioBanxico().encode('Latin-1'))
res = xml_tree.find('.//*[@IDSERIE="SF60653"]/*')
data = res.attrib

print "TIME_PERIOD: {}\nOBS_VALUE: {}".format(data["TIME_PERIOD"], data["OBS_VALUE"])
```

**Salida:**

> TIME_PERIOD: 2017-11-23
>   OBS_VALUE: 18.8242

Con lo anterior obtenemos los datos correspondientes a:

> "Tipo de cambio pesos por dólar E.U.A. Tipo de cambio para solventar obligaciones denominadas en moneda extranjera Fecha de liquidación"

Si lo que quieres es:

> "Tipo de cambio pesos por dólar E.U.A. Tipo de cambio para solventar obligaciones denominadas en moneda extranjera Fecha de determinación (FIX)"

debes usar :

```
res = xml_tree.find('.//*[@IDSERIE="SF43718"]/*')
```

Se usa el valor del atributo `IDSERIE` para filtrar el cambio deseado.

Tambíén podríamos usar expresiones regulares directamente en vez de recurrir a parsear el xml.